# würde arbeiten können vs arbeiten könnte

Tags: grammaticality

Auf einer Sprachenlernen-Website habe ich den Satz korrigiert bekommen. Und zwar wurde:

> „Eine meiner größten Sorgen ist ein Pflegefall zu werden, denn in diesem Fall ich wahrscheinlich nicht arbeiten könnte.“

zum

> „Eine meiner größten Sorgen ist ein Pflegefall zu werden, denn in diesem Fall würde ich wahrscheinlich nicht arbeiten können.“

Ich dachte, dass bei Modalverben in Konjunktiv 2, die Form mit „würde“ vermieden werden sollte. Ist der Satz mit „könnte“ auch grammatikalisch korrekt und wurde nur wegen des Stils korrigiert?

Comment: Dann müsste es aber heißen: *... denn in diesem Fall könnte ich wahrscheinlich nicht arbeiten.*

Comment: Der erste Satz könnte auch wie folgt korrigiert werden: _„Eine meiner größten Sorgen ist ein Pflegefall zu werden, denn in diesem Fall  könnte ich wahrscheinlich nicht arbeiten.“_

Comment: Die Konstruktion mit "würde" könnte auch als Konjunkjtive Futur angesehen werden - was bei einer auf die Zukunft gerichtetet Sorge ja durchaus Sinn ergibt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Könnte* can be used, but the word order is incorrect because **denn** does not require verb-last order:

> Eine meiner größten Sorgen ist ein Pflegefall zu werden, denn in diesem Fall könnte ich wahrscheinlich nicht arbeiten.

In this respect, **denn** differs from **weil** which does require verb-last order:

> Eine meiner größten Sorgen ist ein Pflegefall zu werden, weil ich in diesem Fall wahrscheinlich nicht arbeiten könnte.

Comment: Why in English???

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt keinen Unterschied zwischen "würde arbeiten können" und "arbeiten könnte", aber, ich glaube, was passiert ist, ist dass aufgrund eines anderen Fehlers in deinem Satz, nämlich falsche Wortstellung, wollte derjenige dich korrigieren, und konnte dann selbst entscheiden, welche Form er in dem korrigierten Satz verwenden will, und zwar zwischen:

> [...] denn in diesem Fall könnte ich wahrscheinlich nicht arbeiten.

und:

> [...] denn in diesem Fall würde ich wahrscheinlich nicht arbeiten können.

Er hat einfach die zweite Variante gewählt.

Comment: Es gibt keinen *inhaltlichen* Unterschied. Aber es gibt natürlich einen Unterschied: diverse Wortstellungen müssen angepasst werden.